# reduce the maximum capacity of a .vdi file

Tags: virtualbox

I am using linux. I have a dynamically alloted.vdi (virtual disk) with maximum capacity of 5.5gb. Presnetly the stuff inside is 500 mb and the stuff may increase till 750 mb

I want to reduce the maximum capacity from 5.5 gb to 1gb.  Because my host system has only 3gb left and when i try to use the vdi (of max capacity 5.5gb) it doesnt work. If i shrink the harddisks maximum capacity to 1 gb then this vdi will open in virtual box.

is there any command using vboxmanage.

I also heard that if we convert to raw image we can then shrink.

so how to convert img and shrink

Comment: aren't there already shrink and defragment command in virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to resize ur vdi and then reboot your vm with gparted live iso file http://gparted.org/livecd.php  and resize it using gparted.

VBoxmanage modifyhd MyLinux.vdi --resize 100000

Comment: i am asking about shrinking. because vboxmanage cannot reduce the size

Comment: you should use --compact. See the forum here you can do it using gparted and vboxmanage.  

http://blogs.bu.edu/mhirsch/2012/11/compacting-reducing-maximum-size-of-vdi-files-for-virtualbox/